# How can i make chunks of 15 minutes from two terminal points of time stamp

Tags: php, for-loop

How can i make chunks of 15 minutes from two terminal points  of time stamp.Like,i have a given span of time say 6:00 PM to 10:00 PM. I want to divide this time span into chunks of 15 minutes like,
6:00-6:15
6:15-6:30
6:30-6:45 and so on  upto 10:00 pm

Please any one can help?

Comment: How do you want to use these timestamps? Do you simply want an output of the times? Do you want an array of times? DateTime objects?

Comment: Seems like you've already done it. What part of translating your example to code are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need something like:

```
$tz    = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
$from  = new DateTime('2013-11-13 18:00:00', $tz);
$to    = new DateTime('2013-11-13 22:00:00', $tz);
$times = array();

while ($from <= $to) {
    $times[] = $from->format('r');
    $from->modify('+15 minutes');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `DatePeriod` class:

```
$begin = new DateTime('6:00 PM');
$end = new DateTime('10:00 PM');
$end = $end->modify('+15 minutes'); // to get the last interval, too

$interval = new DateInterval('PT15M');
$timerange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);

foreach($timerange as $time){
    echo $time->format("h:i") . "<br>";
}
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/67104)

Comment: Love this one. `DatePeriod` is a new one on me!